# Where do the files that I download go?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I use the Ubuntu One Files app for Android on my HTC Desire and downloaded one of my files. My questions is this though, where exactly do the files you download go? I can't find the file anywhere on my phone :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files goes to:

```
/sdcard/u1/Ubuntu One/
```

Regards.

ps.: Make sure to refresh the cache of your Android file browser.

Answer (score 3):

Should be on your SD card under /mnt/sdcard/u1. I just tested this on my Samsung M920 running Android 2.2. Hope this helps.